# How can I connect multiple bones to one?

Tags: modeling, rigging, armature, bones

As seen in the image below, I'd like to connect the tails of bones 1-5 to the head of the target bone, in a way that allows the connected bones to rotate accordingly when moving the target bone.

Is that even possible or does Blender require its usual black magic to make something as simple as that work?

[image: Connect multiple tails to one head]

Comment: Please add some more infos. Should the 1-5 bones stretch to follow the target? Should they only point at it? Because if the answer is not for both, then 3 bones are enough to deny any possibility, and this is geometry and not Blender-related.

Comment: The goal is to have 1-5 move together with the target bone (up and down etc.), and the other bones connected to 1-5 should be fixed at their heads and moving at their tails.

Comment: Hi, If I understand it clearly, you want to move the Target bone. When doing so, Bone 1-5 should follow the Target bone. And the bones attached to 1-5 should have their tails connected to bones 1-5 without moving their heads. Is this right?

Comment: Yes, that's my goal. Imagine the target bone as a car's wheel hub that moves up and down or rotates left and right, and the bones connected to 1-5 as the suspension wishbones that are supposed to connect the car body (bone heads) with the wheel hub (bone tails).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Bones 1,2,3,4,5,suspens, are all child of bone "control", which can move up and down and rotate left/right.

Suspens has a "stretch to" constraint pointing to "car" bone. Bones A,B and C have a "stretch to" constraint pointing at 2,1 and 5.

Car and Car2 are parented also.

[image]